# Show that $T(S^n) \times \mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

> Show that $T(S^n) \times \mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

First how $S^n=f^{-1}(1)$ with $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=||x||^2$ then for all $x \in S^{n}$, $Tx(S^n)=\{ v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} ;  (df_x)(v)=0 \}$ and hence is easy to see that $T(S^n)=\{ (x,v) \in S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} ; \langle x,v \rangle =0 \}$ then
$$T(S^n) \times \mathbb{R} =\{(x,v,t) ; x \in S^n, \langle x,v \rangle=0, t \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
And
$$S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} =\{ (x,w); x \in S^n, w \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\}$$

then i try to found one diffeomorphism such that maps the last two entries of $T(S^n) \times \mathbb{R}$ in the last entry of $S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} $ but i now sure how proceded.

Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Comment: One idea: consider $$T(S^n)\times \mathbb{R} \ni (x,v,t) \mapsto (x,v + tx)$$

Comment: Make the homeomorphism it is probably a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Insisting on @Thomas hint: the idea is that for a submanifold $N$ of $\Bbb R^k$, $TN\oplus \nu N = N\times \Bbb R^k$, where $\nu N$ is the normal bundle, whose fibres $\nu_xN$ are $T_xN^{\perp}$.

Comment: @Thomas is that function a diffeomorphism? i show that is smooth and bijective but i not sure if the inverse is smooth

Comment: @Winter_Spartan to show the inverse is smooth there are (at least) two alternatives: i) use the inverse function theorem, ii) write down the inverse map explicitly and show it's smooth. Approach ii) is rather easy in this case.

Comment: @Winter_Spartan You should write an answer to your own question based on Thomas' suggestion. Note that $(v + tx) \cdot x = t$, thus the inverse of Thomas' map will be $(x,w) \mapsto (x, w - (w\cdot x) x, w\cdot x)$.